# Why Liquibase docker container can't connect to Mysql docker container?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, liquibase

When I execute my docker-compose it shows that liquibase can't connect to MySQL:

> am-liquibase_1  | Unexpected error running Liquibase:
> liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:
> liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created
> to jdbc:mysql://am-mysql:3307/am?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false with
> driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver.  Could not create connection to
> database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  am-mysql:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=am
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rse_pass_root
  am-liquibase:
    image: "liquibase/liquibase"
    links:
      - am-mysql
    volumes:
      - ./../../../datalake-schema/mysql-migrations:/liquibase/changelog
    command: --changeLogFile=db.changelog-am-db.xml --url=jdbc:mysql://am-mysql:3307/am?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false --username=root --password=rse_pass_root update
```

I use macOS if it is important.

Comment: Did you try connecting to `3306`? Are you able to manually connect from `am-liquibase` to `am-mysql`  via telnet? (`docker exec -it am-liquibase` then `telnet am-mysql 3307`)

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko Great hint! it works for 3306. 
Liquibase found MySQL when I replaced port from 3307 by 3306 and removed `&useSSL=false`

Comment: The ports statement publishes the ports to the host, but you're not connecting to the db from the host, you're connecting to it from within the network created by compose. That's why you can resolve the hostname `mysql`, and why you're connecting on the port published by the service (3306) rather than the one you've mounted/published on the host network.

Comment: Please reply as an answer. I will accept it.